# How autoload works?

Tags: elisp, autoload

Assume I have 3 functions in a packages:

```
;;;###autoload
(defun my-funcA () ...)

;;;###autoload
(defun my-funcB () ...)

;;;###autoload
(defun my-func-init () ...)
```

If one of the functions is called, will all functions declaration be loaded?
Put it in another way, if `my-func-init` must be loaded in order to use this package, does it mean all the `autoload`s are redundant?

Comment: Also [What's the mechanism to ensure the autoload functions in emacs autoloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28889446).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On their own, these comments are just comments.

A separate process is used to extract the associated definitions into a loaddefs.el file. When that file is loaded, all of those autoloads are defined. Thus all of the autoloads for a great many libraries can be bundled together into a single file, which is fast to load.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `elisp-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `autoload cookie` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> A magic autoload comment (often called an "autoload cookie")
>   consists of ‘;;;###autoload’, on a line by itself, just before the
>   real definition of the function in its autoloadable source file.
>   The command ‘M-x update-file-autoloads’ writes a corresponding
>   ‘autoload’ call into ‘loaddefs.el’.  (The string that serves as the
>   autoload cookie and the name of the file generated by
>   ‘update-file-autoloads’ can be changed from the above defaults, see
>   below.)  Building Emacs loads ‘loaddefs.el’ and thus calls
>   ‘autoload’.  ‘M-x update-directory-autoloads’ is even more powerful;
>   it updates autoloads for all files in the current directory.

The package manager processes the autoload cookies for any given package, so package authors can simply add those comments as appropriate.

Comment: Is there anyway to know if "the real definition of the function" has been loaded?

Comment: In elisp? `autoloadp`. Interactively? `C-h f` tells you when it's an autoloaded function. If it doesn't say so, then the real definition has been loaded.

Comment: Wait. I found that when I put `(autoload 'my-func-A "my-func")`
`(autoload 'my-func-B "my-func")` and `(autoload 'my-func-init "my-func")` in `.emacs`, if one of them is loaded, all function definitions in my-func is loaded.

Comment: Yes, when an autoloaded function is called, the associated library is loaded.